# Lightning Accordion does not close section

Tags: lightning, accordion

Is it possible to close an accordion section kinda like a expandable section or do i have only the option to swap between them

edit: I want to be able to close an open section instead of just opening another one

Comment: by default, the expanded region is the first one, the attribute that controls this is --> [activeSectionName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_accordion.htm), you can change the behavior to default to none, or do you want to be able to expand multiple regions simopultaneously? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I want to be able to close an open section instead of just opening another one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lightning-accordion and lightning:accordion now support multiple sections. If you enable multi-section support, you can choose to have zero or more sections open at the same time. If you do not enable multi-select, one section will always remain open.

---

Edit: Original Answer

lightning:accordion always has one section open. That's how they're designed to behave. If you need/want to have multiple sections open, or no sections open, you'd have to write your own component set.

Comment: Ok got it,are there any good alternatives to the accordion where i can do this? Preferably in Lightning.

Comment: @Aka - you can add a default accordion and make it hidden through CSS. I tried and it worked for me. In the UI it will look as if all accordions are closed

Comment: lol who designed this system where single accordion sections aren't collapsible

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks for commenting. You can actually do this *now*, if you use the multi-section support feature. This was missing at the time of this answer (as far as I can tell). I've edited this answer to that effect.

Comment: @sfdcfox - how do you programmatically close an accordion section (when there's only 1 section)?

Comment: @jbyrd You need to have `allow-multiple-sections-open` set to true, otherwise `lightning-accordion` will force one section to always be open. Assuming you set that flag, you can then set `active-section-name` to `[]` (an empty array) to close that section. [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/0TjNTHuRUlKmsPrz91cw/src/app.html?p=stories).

Comment: @sfdcfox - setting to an empty array is what I was looking for. Perfect - thanks! Incidentally, I didn't realize you could use a `foreach` directly on a `lightning-accordion-section`